# How to mock api call in angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I am running unit test on api call, I want to mock this and ensure variable that receives data from this api is correctly set, this api must fetch data based on the filter.Please let me know how to mock from api and if posible how to ensure only data fulfilling criteria is fetched?

```
this.http.post<someVar[]>('/api/records', this.filter)
    .subscribe(res => {
      if (res['status'] == "FAILURE") {
        console.log(res['err']);
        this.spinner.hide();
      } else {

        this.data = res['data'];
}
```

to mock from spec.ts

```
 component.filter.from="2019-03-10T22:00:00.000Z";
 component.filter.to="2019-04-11T21:59:59.000Z";
 mockService.getData=of(mockRecords);//didn't work,so used another one
  mockService.getData.and.returnValue(of(mockRecords));
//either of them worked

Also I will mention the filters
 filter = {
    from : "",
    to : "",
    id: "",
    name: "",
    server: ""
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to accomplish this:

First, create a spy:

```
getDataSpy = spyOn(mockService, "getData").and.returnValue(of(mockRecords));
```

And expect like this:

```
it('should succeed', () => {
  // ...setup

  // ...action

  expect(getDataSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(filter);
});
```

And don't forget to import `of`:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
```

Answer (score 0):

````
```
let getDataSpy=spyOn(mockService,"getData").and.returnValue(of(mockRecords));
component.filter.from="2019-03-10T22:00:00.000Z";//10th march
component.filter.to="2019-04-11T21:59:59.000Z";//11th april
fixture.detectChanges();
expect(getDataSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();//fails
expect(getDataSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(filter);//also fails
````